# Any way to restrict targets of page-mod in Mozilla Add-On SDK

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-sdk, mozilla

I am currently working on a Firefox add-on using an SDK which modifies a text content of the page in a specific way.  However, I ran into the following problem.

Let's say I have 2 tabs, both of which have the same site loaded into them.  The site has multiple iframes, some cross-domain.  I need to update only the page in the tab I am currently on.

If I add a worker to a tab using tab.attach(),  I can inject my content-altering code to just that tab so all is great.  Except it doesn't affect iframes.

In order to get to the iframes, I have to to use PageMod using something like this:

```
tabs.on('ready', function(tab) {
    pageMod.PageMod({
            include: tab.url,
            contentScriptFile: self.data.url('./pagemod.js'),
            attachTo: ["top", "frame", "existing"],
            onAttach: function(worker) {
                worker.on('message', function(msg){
                    me.handleMessage(msg);
                });
                tracker.workers.push(worker);
            }
        });
    } 
});
```

It works fine because it attaches workers to the frames as well as the top document, so I can inject my code into all of them.  However, it also affects the other page that I have open in the second tab, since it has the same url.

Is there any way that I can limit the page mod effects only to a current tab?  I don't find anything obvious but maybe I've just been looking at it for too long.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each [tab has an id](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/tabs#id) and you can always access the [current active tab this way](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/tabs#activeTab). So in `onAttach` attribute you can do `if tab.id == tabs.activeTab.id { doSomethingElse(); }`.

Comment: Your comment pointed me to the right path - essentially, on attach I perform a check to see whether the worker.tab.id is the same as tab.id.  If so, it's a worker for the current tab, so I add it into the set of used workers, else I discard.  Thank you.